# Sendgrid email api showing unauthorized error

Tags: email, send, sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to send email through SENDGRID API from

```
https://packagist.org/packages/sendgrid/sendgrid
```

I am using "Hello Email" code from above link

But when I try to run email this is what I am getting

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED
    [1] => Server: nginx
    [2] => Date: Wed, 03 Apr 2019 04:33:59 GMT
    [3] => Content-Type: application/json
    [4] => Content-Length: 62
    [5] => Connection: keep-alive
    [6] => Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
    [7] => Access-Control-Max-Age: 21600
    [8] => Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Link, Location
    [9] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    [10] => Access-Control-Allow-Headers: AUTHORIZATION, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl, X-Recaptcha, X-Request-Source
    [11] => Content-Security-Policy: default-src https://api.sendgrid.com; frame-src 'none'; object-src 'none'
    [12] => X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    [13] => Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
    [14] => 
    [15] => 
)
{"errors":[{"field":null,"message":"authorization required"}]}
```

Even I uploaded on the live server, but still getting same, tried to create 2,3 more API keys with full access but getting the same issue.

Please help me...